# Php laravel TokenMismatchException request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

am try to send request by post form from but error TokenMismatchException

here is my controller code

```
public function postSaveedit(Request $request) {
    $var1 = $request->input('title'); //name on the form
    $var2 = $request->input('meaning'); //name on the form
    $words = User::where("title", $var1)->update(array("meaning" => $var2));

    return view('dict.watch', compact('words'));
}
```

here is view code.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('index/saveedit') }}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value='{{ $words->first()->title }}' type="text" name="title">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text" name="meaning">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit">
        <span></span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

thnak you for your help

Comment: am use Route::controller('index', 'IndexController'); and i add use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: add this line in your form <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />

Comment: <input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}"  name="meaning" type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" > not work can't type in form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing:

> Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user
>   session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that
>   the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the
>   application.
>
> Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include
>   a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection
>   middleware will be able to validate the request. To generate a hidden
>   input field _token containing the CSRF token, you may use the
>   csrf_field helper function

Just add this line inside your form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ URL::to('index/saveedit') }}">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token(); }}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Title:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value='{{ $words->first()->title }}' type="text" name="title">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Meaning:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text" name="meaning">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit">
        <span></span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"> i can't type my input in form because hidden

Comment: am edit form
<input class="form-control" value="{{ $words->first()->meaning }}" type="text" name="meaning">

Comment: Edited, Please check.

Comment: how can i return to view page and compact my new update object

Comment: db have been update but after i call
return view('dict.watch', compact('words'));
it say nvalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

Comment: You can read it from here https://laravel.com/docs/master/views, if you have problem then let me know